# Convert OCTL character to ISO-8859-15(html) with java

Tags: java, decoder

how can i conver a String that contains OCTL character to ISO-8859-15, to make understable. 
I'm working with java. ty.

i'm trying to recuperate a value for a informix bbdd, an i put inside String, but when i show in view i saw Espa\321a---> and i wanna see ESPAÑA. I've looking for an saw that \321 is a OCTL is this possible ?

HTML     OCTL   HEX   CMP   CHR   MEANING

Ñ | \321 | =D1 | N ~ | (Ñ) | Capital N, tilde

so OCTL = \321 = Ñ

I try this but don't work for me, i'm doing sth wrong.

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("OCTL");
        CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
        CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();

        try {

            ByteBuffer bbuf = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(rs.getString(Constants.DES_PAIS_COM)));

            ByteBuffer and then to a string.

            CharBuffer cbuf = decoder.decode(bbuf);
            String s = cbuf.toString();
            deuteDetall.setDesPaisCom(s);

        } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {



        }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "OCTL character"? Bear in mind that a *string* never has an encoding... or rather, it's always UTF-16. It would really help if you'd give more details and an example.

Comment: What do characters have to do with a standard about _"Road vehicles -- Passenger-car and trailer combinations -- Lateral stability test"_? You probably mean ISO-8859, but then you still need to specify the exact characterset (eg ISO-8859-1)

Comment: Looks like `\321` is an octal escape.

Comment: and how i can transform to HMTL(ISO-8859-1)? maybe i didn't explain really well.

Comment: What “view” are you showing the string in?

Comment: rs.getString(Constants.DES_PAIS_COM), jdbcTemplate that attatcks an informix bbdd, rs.getString give me ESPA\321A in informix is correct the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\321` is octal, in hex D1, (3*64+2*8+1).

```
String s = "...";
Pattern OCTAL = Pattern.compile("\\\\(\\d\\d\\d)");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
byte[] b1 = new byte[1];
Matcher m = OCTAL.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    String replacement = m.group(): // default original
    try {
        b1[0] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 8);
        replacement = new String(b1, "ISO-8859-15");
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //...
    }
    m.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
}
m.appendTail(sb);
s = sb.toString();
```

Comment: sb.appendReplacement ?? is java 1.7? ty for your time. i can use..wtf.

Comment: Sorry, `m.appendReplacement`. `=D1` would function similar. `N~` requires listing all possibilities (`s.replace("N~", "\u00D1")`).